# Python gunicorn duplicate logs

Tags: python, logging, kubernetes, gunicorn

I wrote a module file that formats logs according to Google Stackdriver json standards. For doing so, I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/retailmenot-engineering/formatting-python-logs-for-stackdriver-5a5ddd80761c).

This is my module:

```
import logging
import sys
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger


class _MaxLevelFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, highest_log_level):
        self._highest_log_level = highest_log_level

    def filter(self, log_record):
        return log_record.levelno <= self._highest_log_level


class StackdriverJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter, object):
    def __init__(self, fmt="%(levelname) %(message)", style='%', *args, **kwargs):
        jsonlogger.JsonFormatter.__init__(self, fmt=fmt, *args, **kwargs)

    def process_log_record(self, log_record):
        log_record['severity'] = log_record['levelname']
        del log_record['levelname']
        return super(StackdriverJsonFormatter, self).process_log_record(log_record)


formatter = StackdriverJsonFormatter()

"""
//////////////// INFO HANDLER ///////////////
"""
# A handler for low level logs that should be sent to STDOUT
info_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
info_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
info_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
info_handler.addFilter(_MaxLevelFilter(logging.WARNING))
"""----------------------------------------"""

"""
//////////////// ERROR HANDLER ///////////////
"""
# A handler for high level logs that should be sent to STDERR
error_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
error_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
error_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
"""----------------------------------------"""

try:
    root_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
except:
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
# root logger default level is WARNING, so we'll override to be DEBUG
root_logger.addHandler(info_handler)
root_logger.addHandler(error_handler)
```

It logs things formatted, although it duplicates the log one being json formatted and the other being text formatted:

```
[2018-04-17 12:40:48 +0000] [24255] [INFO] This is an INFO
{"message": "This is an INFO", "severity": "INFO"}
[2018-04-17 12:40:48 +0000] [24255] [ERROR] This is an ERROR
{"message": "This is an ERROR", "severity": "ERROR"}
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the `ERROR` tag on GCP StackDriver for all the logs. I used the below code  and It worked. All the logs are correctly tagged without any duplicate logs.

```
class StackDriverJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter, object):
    def __init__(self, fmt="%(levelname) %(message)", style='%', *args, **kwargs):
        jsonlogger.JsonFormatter.__init__(self, fmt=fmt, *args, **kwargs)
    def process_log_record(self, log_record):
        log_record['severity'] = log_record['levelname']
        del log_record['levelname']
        return super(StackDriverJsonFormatter, self).process_log_record(log_record)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
formatter = StackDriverJsonFormatter()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log= logging.getLogger()
log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the reason you were seeing ERROR tags in GCP may be that any output sent to stderr that the fluent logger doesn't understand, such as the text formatted echoes of your formatted messages, gets tagged as ERROR.